# Improving the display of rotated text

Tags: java, text, rotation, processing

I have the following code that's adapted from an online example for rotating text. The code works fine in that it rotates the text to the correct angle, but I would to know if there is a way to improve the accuracy and crispness of the rotated text.  On my display it looks as though the rotated text is 'stepped' rather than smooth.

```
PFont f;
String message = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
float theta, x;

void setup() {
  size(800, 200);
  f = createFont("Arial",20,true);
}

void draw() { 
 // background(255);
  fill(0);
  textFont(f);    // Set the font
  translate(x,height/2);  // Translate to the center
  rotate(theta);                // Rotate by theta
  textAlign(LEFT);            
  text(message,0,0);            
  theta += 0.1;                // Increase rotation
  x += textWidth(message);
  if (x>800){noLoop(); }
}
```

I've amended by example to help display the difference.  In the new code I've change the text to a string of underscores and drawn a reference line in red too.  If it works the same on your machine you should see a staggering in the black line created by the underscores.

```
String message = "________";
float theta, x;
PFont f;

void setup() {
  size(800, 200);
  f = loadFont("ArialMT-20.vlw");
  smooth();
}

void draw() { 
  fill(0);
  textFont(f);    // Set the font

  translate(x,height/2);  // Translate to the center
  rotate(theta);                // Rotate by theta

  text(message,0,0);

  stroke(255,0,0);
  strokeWeight(2);
  line(0,0,textWidth(message),0);

  theta += 0.1;                // Increase rotation
  x += textWidth(message);
  if (x>800){noLoop(); }
}
```

For me it gives the following output, but I know this will differ if run on a Mac:

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Maybe you are looking for anti-alisasing? http://www.universalwebservices.net/web-programming-resources/java/anti-aliasing-creating-anti-alias-text-in-java

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is Processing.org code so it's possible to copy and paste into the IDE and run.  You're right, I am looking for the text to be anti-aliased and as I understand it it should be. When I create the Font the 'true' option selects anti-aliasing.

Comment: can you post a screenshot ? I've pasted your code and it looks smooth(anti-aliased) to me. Calling `smooth()` didn't make a difference. Also I've noticed the text looks nice with the `JAVA2D` renderer, but not `P2D`

Answer (score 1):

Try tweaking the [`RenderingHints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html):

- Set [fractional metrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS) to [on](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON)
- Set [text antialiasing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING) to [on](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON) or a sub-pixel setting matching your display
- Set [stroke control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#KEY_STROKE_CONTROL) to [pure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#VALUE_STROKE_PURE)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to plot the text (not rotated) in a BufferedImage, and then rotate the image. Something like this:

```
BufferedImage buff = getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(textWidth, textHeight); //create an image with the dimensions of the text
Graphics2D g2d = buff.createGraphics();
g2d.drawString(yourText); //draw the text without transformations
g2d.dispose();

//apply the rotation transform to g, the Graphics from your component
g.drawImage(buff, textPosX, textPosY, null); //there you go
```